# Specific Footer on only one section

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

How do I add a specific footer on only one section? I want the same footer on all but one section (where I want no footer)? Thanks!

Comment: I was going to suggest that you use `\fancypagestyle{footless}{...}` to create a new pagestyle `\ps@footless`, but it turns out that the new pagestyle simply calls `\ps@fancy` after making changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the package `fancyhdr`, using the page style `fancy`, you can modify the footer in the document with the command `\fancyfoot`. Here's an example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\newcommand{\blankpage}{\null\newpage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}
\section{First section}
\blankpage
\blankpage
\fancyfoot{}
\section{Second section}
\blankpage
\blankpage
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\section{Third section}
\blankpage
\blankpage
\end{document}
```

This example outputs a document where the page numbers appear on the footer in the first and third sections, but the footer is empty in the section section.

Comment: I'll test this out when I get a chance. For the time being, I'll accept this solution.